# Angular.js and Genshi - conflicts using $

Tags: python, html, angularjs, turbogears2, genshi

Hi
I'm writing a WebApp using python, turbogears 2.2, and Genshi for my view\templates.

On the view side, I'm also using Angular.js. most of the time it they work together. My problem is – when I want to use some stuff like $index inside an ng-repeat I cannot. When I try doing that, I get a **genshi.template.eval.UndefinedError**

here is some html code to demonstrate:

```html
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:py="http://genshi.edgewall.org/"
  xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" ng-app="orderItemEditApp">

... some code ...

<tr ngrepeat="item in items">
    <td>{{$index}}</td>

....
```

Is there a way to use $index (or other stuff) with genshi and angular.js?
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use double dollar signs in your Genshi template for escaping:

```
<td>{{$$index}}</td>
```

Will output:

```
<td>{{$index}}</td>
```

Comment: Thanks, I didnt think about escaping. [Escaping in Genshi](http://genshi.edgewall.org/wiki/Documentation/templates.html#escaping)

Comment: There is also a short example of Angular with TG on TG documentation that explains that and how to properly load Resources from TGRestController: http://turbogears.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook/Crud/restapi.html#leveraging-your-rest-api-on-angularjs